# IE9 Kiosk Mode scheduled task opens behind taskbar

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, kiosk

I've set up a scheduled task in Windows 7 Pro to open up Internet Explorer 9 (x86 version) in kiosk mode. The scheduled task executes when a certain user logs in, and this user is logged in automatically when Windows starts.

This is the command I'm using to start IE:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k http://example.com
```

So far so good - the computer boots up, the user gets logged in, and IE opens up in kiosk mode. The problem is that IE seems to open behind the taskbar - so the taskbar (start menu, pinned programs, etc.) appears at the bottom of the window, and the bottom of the IE window is visible through the taskbar (since the taskbar is translucent).

Is there anything I can do, preferably without installing any third party programs (although I will go for that option if none other is available), to ensure that the IE9 kiosk window always opens in front of the taskbar?

Comment: Have you tried turning auto-hide on for the taskbar? Have you tried a Startup script GPO instead?

Comment: Setting the taskbar to auto-hide will do nicely - I didn't even think of that!

Comment: Ok great, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the taskbar to Auto-hide and that will prevent it from showing above your full screen application.

Comment: You're very welcome.